# Initializing static class members in an initialize function

Tags: c++, opengl, static

I have a private static member of a c++ **static** class (very similar to a singleton class, but removes the need for allocating an instance of the class since it is done automatically).

Anyways, I want to initialize this static member. Typically, one would go about this by doing the following

Example.h

```
class Example
{
  private:
    static OtherClass _value;
    Example() {}
};
```

Example.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"
OtherClass Example::_value(constructor arguments)
```

The code I am currently writing won't allow this. Essentially I am writing a DebugDraw class for OpenGL and the class will contain its own static member for a Shader object that will create the OpenGL shader. If I use the above method, the Shader will be constructed before glew is initialized, which will cause some major problems.

This is the solution I am playing with.

Example.h

```
class Example
{
  public:
    Initialize();
  private:
    static OtherClass _value;
    Example(){}
};
```

Example.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"

Example::Initialize()
{
  OtherClass _value(constructor arguments)
  // Other code that I will need to add
}
```

Code written like this will compile, but will it have the desired effect I am looking for (initializing the static class member)? What does the mean for the static members before the Initialize function is called (I do intend on putting an initialized bool in there as well)?

Thanks

Here is the actual code I am working with.

DebugDraw.h

```
#ifndef DEBUGDRAW_H
#define DEBUGDRAW_H

#include <GLM\glm\vec4.hpp>

#include "Shader.h"

class DebugDraw
{
  public:
    static void Initialize();
    static void Line();
    static void Triangle();
    static void Box();
    static void Color();
  private:
    static glm::vec4 _color;
    static Shader _shader;
    DebugDraw() {}
};

#endif // !DEBUGDRAW_H
```

DebugDraw.cpp

```
#include "DebugDraw.h"

void DebugDraw::Initialize()
{
  glm::vec4 _color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  Shader _shader("Shader/debug.vert", "Shader/debug.frag");
  _shader.Use();
}
```

^ This does compile ^

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? Missing `;` after the end of class declarations.

Comment: yeaym this code was an example. I didn't want to post the opengl code that I am writing. I just want to know about this one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the mean for the static members before the Initialize function is called (I do intend on putting an initialized bool in there as well)?

You're creating a local variable called `_val` (this should be `_value`?), which has nothing to do with your static variable. As such, your code won't even link.

---

To do what you're intending, you would initialise the variable, just like you've shown in your first Example.cpp, but without any constructor arguments:

```
#include "Example.h"
OtherClass Example::_value;
```

Make sure that the no-argument constructor doesn't perform any actual initialisation! We're going to delay this by making an `OtherClass::initialize` method.

```
#include "Example.h"
OtherClass Example::_value;

Example::Initialize()
{
  Example::_value.initialize(...);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could make `_value` a pointer, assign it to `NULL` and allocate it on the heap when you need it:

```
#include "Example.h"
OtherClass *Example::_value = NULL;

Example::Initialize()
{
  Example::_value = new OtherClass(...);
}
```

Don't forget to `delete` it when you don't need it anymore. Or, if you can use C++11, use an `std::shared_ptr<OtherClass>` instead.

Comment: Sorry, edited `_val` to `_value`. So what would that mean for the second implementation (where I perform the static initialization in the `Example::Initialize()` function)? I was going to use the method where I have an Initialize function in OtherClass, but there were some specifics that turned me away from doing that. Really a default constructor for the class just seemed like a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? In the second implementation, you'd still be using a `static` variable, but it would be a pointer and would start off as `NULL` until you set it to an instance of `OtherClass`.

Comment: I am referring to the second implementation provided in the original question. Is `_value` in the `Example::Initialize()` function creating a new variable on the stack, or is it initializing the static member `_value`. Since they have the same identifier, I am not fully sure which is happening.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. It'd still create a variable on the stack.

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense. Thanks for the help.